# Indexing and selecting from variable data in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list "dates":

```
['2017-04-30',
 '2012-09-30',
 '2016-09-30',
 '2012-10-31']
```

and a series, 'AAPL':

```
2012-04-30    1170.294527
2012-05-31    1528.785307
2012-06-30    1525.203742
2012-07-31    1408.036492
...
2017-07-31    1830.33231
```

I'm trying to select the next three dates for each given date in the list. E.g. for '2017-04-30' in the "dates" , i want to select '2017-05-31' , '2017-06-30' , and '2017-07-31' from the series.

My expected output is to select be able to select the 3 dates in the series that are after the dates in the list.

Answer (score 0):

First:

> E.g. for '2017-04-30' in the "dates" , i want to select '2017-05-31' , '2017-06-30' , and '2017-07-31' from the series.

but you haven't '2017-04-30' in the series. But okay. 
For example if you don't set any circumstances:

```
dates = [
    '2017-04-30',
    '2012-09-30',
    '2016-09-30',
    '2012-10-31'
]

series = [
    '2017-04-30 1170.294527',
    '2017-05-31 1528.785307',
    '2017-06-30 1525.203742',
    '2017-07-31 1408.036492'
]

for d in dates:
    for i, s in enumerate(series):
        if s.split(' ')[0] == d:
            print('{}: {}'.format(d, list([m for m in series])[i:i + 3]))
```

This give you exactly what you want. **Without** series **array borders considering**. 
i.e. for

```
series = [
    '2017-04-30 1170.294527',
    '2017-05-31 1528.785307',
    '2017-06-30 1525.203742',
    '2017-07-31 1408.036492'
]
```

the output will be

```
2017-04-30: ['2017-05-31 1528.785307', '2017-06-30 1525.203742', '2017-07-31 1408.036492']
```

for

```
series = [
'2017-05-31 1528.785307',
'2017-06-30 1525.203742',
'2017-04-30 1170.294527',
'2017-07-31 1408.036492'
]
```

the output will be

```
2017-04-30: ['2017-07-31 1408.036492']
```

and for

```
series = [
'2017-05-31 1528.785307',
'2017-06-30 1525.203742',
'2017-07-31 1408.036492',
'2017-04-30 1170.294527'
]
```

the output will be

```
2017-04-30: []
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that both of your inputs are list of date strings.

```
first_list = ['2017-04-30',
 '2012-09-30',
 '2016-09-30',
 '2012-10-31']

second_list = ['2012-04-30',
'2012-05-31',
'2012-06-30',
'2012-07-31',
'2017-04-30',
'2017-05-31',
'2017-06-30',
'2017-07-31',
'2017-07-31']
for each_date in first_list:
    if each_date in second_list:
        index = second_list.index(each_date)
        print "For the date ", each_date, " next 3 dates are: ", second_list[index+1], second_list[index+2], second_list[index+3]
```